# QML text doesn't update unless I resize window

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have the following Python code

```
import sys
import os
import threading
from time import sleep

from PySide2.QtCore import QObject
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


def add_text(log_text):
    i = 1
    while True:
        text = log_text.property("text")
        log_text.setProperty("text", text + "\n" + str(i))
        i += 1
        sleep(1)


app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))

root = engine.rootObjects()[0]
log_text = root.findChild(QObject, 'log_text')
x = threading.Thread(target=add_text, args=(log_text,))
x.start()

if not engine.rootObjects():
    sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the following QML file

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.13
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13


Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    RowLayout {
        id: main_row
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0

        Rectangle {
            id: log_background
            width: 250
            height: 480
            color: "#515151"
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            Text {
                id: log_text
                objectName: "log_text"
                color: "#ffffff"
                anchors.fill: parent
                font.pixelSize: 12
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignBottom
            }
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            id: image_buttons_column
            width: 100
            height: 100
            spacing: 0

            Image {
                id: image
                width: 504
                height: 429
                source: "qrc:/qtquickplugin/images/template_image.png"
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                cache: true
                smooth: true
                mirror: false
                mipmap: false
                autoTransform: false
                asynchronous: false
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            }

            RowLayout {
                id: buttons_row
                width: 100
                height: 100
                spacing: 0

                Button {
                    id: button_yes
                    objectName: "button_yes"
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    palette {
                        button: "#64e764"
                    }
                    font.pointSize: 16
                    text: "Yes"
                    signal pressed
                    onClicked: pressed()
                }
                Button {
                    id: button_maybe
                    objectName: "button_maybe"
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    palette {
                        button: "#ffff00"
                    }
                    font.pointSize: 16
                    text: "Maybe"
                    signal pressed
                    onClicked: pressed()
                }
                Button {
                    id: button_no
                    objectName: "button_no"
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    palette {
                        button: "#ff726f"
                    }
                    font.pointSize: 16
                    text: "No"
                    signal pressed
                    onClicked: pressed()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above python script, the text updates itself once, showing the number 1 and then stops. Whenever I resize the window, all of the numbers that should've been added suddenly show up as they should. How can I get the text area to update itself whenever the text is changed instead of whenever the window has been resized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to manipulate Qt from a thread other than the main one. This will not work and will likely lead to crashes. Almost all GUI toolkits can only be manipulated from the main thread.

In this particular case, I would use a QML `Timer` object in your QML file instead. It will execute on the main thread and achieve the same purpose. Like this:

```
            Text {
                id: log_text
                objectName: "log_text"
                color: "#ffffff"
                anchors.fill: parent
                font.pixelSize: 12
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignBottom

                Timer {
                    interval: 1000
                    running: true
                    repeat: true

                    property int i: 1
                    onTriggered: {
                        log_text.text += `\n${i}`;
                        i += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

If this has to be done in a separate thread for some other reason, you will need to call from that thread to a handler on the main thread to actually manipulate Qt via a signal. The Qt signal mechanism detects when signals are crossing threads and properly schedules the signal on the receiving side on its event queue.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how I could achieve this with a QML Timer, the examples I find on the internet simply do not work.

Comment: Ok, added a Timer example for you.